# Jquery fadeOut method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

First of all I'm a complete beginner.

I want the color-blocks to fade-out before switching. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92Sb4/) and my current code.

```
$('#6').css({'background-color': '#FFFF00'});

setTimeout(function(){
    $('#11').css({'background-color': '#008000'}).siblings().css({'background-color': '#2e2e2e'});
}, 500);

setTimeout(function(){
    $('#9').css({'background-color': '#0000CD'}).siblings().css({'background-color': '#2e2e2e'});
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){
    $('#4').css({'background-color' : '#FFFFFF' }).siblings().css({'background-color' : '#2e2e2e'});}, 1500);

setTimeout(function(){
    $('#14').css({'background-color' : '#FF8C00'}).siblings().css({'background-color' : '#2e2e2e'});}, 2000);
```

---

I want the color-blocks to fade-out before switching, but I have no idea how to do it. I would really appreciate it if someone could help.

Comment: `$('#6').fadeOut().css({'background-color' : '#FFFFFF' }).fadeIn(); `it should work, But I am not really sure if it's what you think about.

Comment: fade out also have callback function so you can use it instead of `setTimeout` http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Maciej! It works! Could you also tell me how to use the callback function in my case. Thanks!

Comment: Can somebody tell me why it's downvoted? it's not the best question, but everyone can be beginner. @user3125295 added code and jsFiddle which is not happening to often.

Comment: I added my solution as answer and upgraded it a little bit, so feel free to accept it if you think it's proper answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/92Sb4/10/.

```
$('#6').fadeOut(500,function(){

$(this)
.css({'background-color':'#FFFF00'})
.fadeIn(500);
$(this)
.siblings()
.css({'background-color': '#2e2e2e'})});
```

To animate color you can use color [animation plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) or just toggle classes using `removeClass` `addClass` or `toggleClass` and animate color using css3.